# iPad - Page view controller - show next view controller

Tags: ipad, ios5

I'm using page view controller with a button on top right. on click of it it will show pop over view which has table view. (Table view has list of URL's)

On selecting a cell, i want to push a view controller which has web view that shows the URL in the cell.

Upto showing pop over its fine. I'm not able to find a solution on how to push another view controller.
Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a protocol in my table view controller class and implementing the delegate methods in Root View controller. When the cell is clicked I am calling appropriate delegate method which instantiates the next view controller and pushes it from navigation controller.